# Execute a python script and get script pid in c

Tags: python, c, process

I want to execute a python script in c to get a custom executable name but all my attempts basically failed as it always involves some child process where I don't have the pid to 'contact' it...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

void  SIGINT_handler(int);
void  SIGTERM_handler(int);
void  SIGUSR1_handler(int);

int   ShmID;
pid_t *ShmPTR;
pid_t c_pid; // should be the script pid

int main(void) {
  pid_t p_pid = getpid();
  key_t MyKey;
  if (signal(SIGINT, SIGINT_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
    printf("SIGINT install error\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (signal(SIGTERM, SIGTERM_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
    printf("SIGTERM install error\n");
    exit(2);
  }
  if (signal(SIGUSR1, SIGUSR1_handler) == SIG_ERR) {
    printf("SIGUSR1 install error\n");
    exit(3);
  }
  MyKey   = ftok(".", 's');
  ShmID   = shmget(MyKey, sizeof(pid_t), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
  ShmPTR  = (pid_t *) shmat(ShmID, NULL, 0);
  *ShmPTR = p_pid;

  //---This is where I'm stuck---
}

void  SIGINT_handler(int sig) {
  signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
  kill(c_pid, sig);//send interrupt signal to pyton script
  printf("From SIGINT: just got a %d (SIGINT ^C) signal\n", sig);
  signal(sig, SIGINT_handler);
}

void  SIGTERM_handler(int sig) {
  signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
  kill(c_pid, sig);//send terminate signal to python script
  printf("From SIGTERM: just got a %d (SIGTERM ^\\) signal"
                          " and is about to quit\n", sig);
  shmdt(ShmPTR);
  shmctl(ShmID, IPC_RMID, NULL);

  exit(3);
}

void  SIGUSR1_handler(int sig) {
  signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
  kill(c_pid, sig);//send user signal 1 to python script
  printf("From SIGUSR1: just got a %d (SIGUSR1 ^C) signal\n", sig);
  signal(sig, SIGUSR1_handler);
}
```

> Disclaimer: I'm more of a beginner in C

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Sorry but I also am not sure to understand; do you want to change the process name like with [`pthread_setname_np`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* that you want is a way  to create an executable from a Python script. There are a few tools to do this:

- [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)  (Windows)
- [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) (multiple platforms)
- [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) (multiple platforms)

Alternatively you can [embed the Python interpreter in C](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html).